# Wrong app display on both physical and virtual device

Tags: android, resolution, android-studio-3.4

I tried on both emulator and physical device ,with different layouts, but app shows only about sixty percent of layout,like its exceeding the visible screen and some component goes under.

I tried to use a scroll view,but no success.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#242323"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="715dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="blah blah"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="press"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: For you `RelativeLayout`'s both `width` and `height` use `match_parent`.

Comment: @Touf Touf, I suggest you learn constraint layout first. It is a great layout. You won't need a relative layout when you are using a constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,try to change this:
from

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="715dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

to

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
```

Comment: There still a part exceeding the screen resolution,i tried you're modifications and make the two component right in the middle but still seeing a part going under .

Comment: Use Relative layout or linear layout instead of ConstraintLayout .

Comment: I tried to remove the toolbar,and the component are almost in the right place in emulator,but still the same problem on my physical device(Xperia XA2 ULTRA, 6.0 inches, 1080 x 1920 pixels, 16:9 ratio (~367 ppi density)).

Comment: Please refer this link for one example:https://javatutorial.net/android-relative-layout-example

Answer (score 0):

When using constraint layout you need to link your views to some other view/boundry. In your case your RelativeLayout was not linked to parent, and you were using an extra Layout so remove the Constraint layout and use just Relative layout. 
That will work.

Try the following xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#242323"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="blah blah"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="press"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried so ,but my problem is that component  near to the top becomes invisible while running on emulator or device!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the relative layout and just use constraint layout only. Note that your button and edittext have to be constrained to the parent view. Learn more about Constraint Layout at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout

Try the following xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#242323"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:hint="blah blah"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/edittext"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="press"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittext" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```